# Create a folder with subfolders and files from a R dataframe

Tags: file-system, r

I have such a dataframe:

```
library(tibble)

dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~level1,~level2,~level3,~level4,
  "Beverages","Water","","",
  "Beverages","Coffee","","",
  "Beverages","Tea","Black tea","",
  "Beverages","Tea","White tea","",
  "Beverages","Tea","Green tea","Sencha",
  "Beverages","Tea","Green tea","Gyokuro",
  "Beverages","Tea","Green tea","Matcha",
  "Beverages","Tea","Green tea","Pi Lo Chun"
)
```

Then I want to create these folders/subfolders/files (this is a file when there's no child):

```
.
|
`- Beverages
   |
   +- Water
   |
   +- Tea
   |  |
   |  +- White tea
   |  |
   |  +- Green tea
   |  |  |
   |  |  +- Sencha
   |  |  |
   |  |  +- Pi Lo Chun
   |  |  |
   |  |  +- Matcha
   |  |  |
   |  |  `- Gyokuro
   |  |
   |  `- Black tea
   |
   `- Coffee
```

I do as follows:

```
paths <- apply(dat, 1L, paste0, collapse = "/")
paths <- gsub("/*$", "", paths)
paths <- stringi::stri_replace_last(paths, "//", fixed = "/")
paths <- strsplit(paths, "//")
folders <- lapply(paths, head, 1L)
files <- lapply(paths, function(path) do.call(file.path, as.list(path)))
lapply(folders, dir.create, recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)
lapply(files, file.create, showWarnings = FALSE)
```

Do you have a better idea?

Maybe this view is better:

```
│
└───Beverages
    │   Coffee
    │   Water
    │
    └───Tea
        │   Black tea
        │   White tea
        │
        └───Green tea
                Gyokuro
                Matcha
                Pi Lo Chun
                Sencha
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
paths <- sub("/+$", "", do.call(file.path, dat))
dirs  <- sub("(.*)/.*", "\\1", paths)
for (dir in unique(dirs)) dir.create(dir, showWarnings = FALSE, recursive = TRUE)
for (file in paths) file.create(file)
```

It's a little simpler in that it only uses `base` R functions (no dependency on the `stringi` package), and it uses fewer operations and functions.

The only possible complexity is in the use of regular expressions, which you already seem familiar with.

1. `"/+$"` matches one or more slashes at the end of a string; we replace these with `""`
2. `"(.*)/.*"` matches the whole string but stores the directory path (everything up to the last slash) into `\\1`.

The use of `unique` can make the execution faster if you have a lot of files in the same directory.

Last, the use of a `for` loop over `lapply` is mostly a matter of preference.